# Recover mail from Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, data-recovery, mail

I have to recover some critical mails from Mozilla Thunderbird installed on my PC. I am not sure how to recover these mails. Kindly help.

Comment: Inadequate information. What do you mean 'recover'? Can you not start thunderbird? What mail server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Trash** folder. If your emails are there, just select the ones you want reverted, and drag it back to your designated folder, e.g., **Inbox**. Otherwise, your emails should be in **Archives**, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

back up profiles folder first:

```
/home/<user>/.thunderbird
```

Try to insert the folder in another thunderbird to see if it's a problem of thunderbird or your profile.